# How to get the value from SelectItem

Tags: gwt, servlets, combobox, webforms, smartgwt

I have a stupid question, how can I get the value selected in the SelectItem (smartgwt) from the httpservletRequest?

Here I build the selectItem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nomeSplit.length - 1; i++) {
   if (!(nomeSplit[i].equals("importador")))    
      list.put(nomeSplit[i], nomeSplit[i]);
}

SelectItem combo = new SelectItem();
combo.setValueMap(list); 
combo.setName("importador");
```

Here I try to get the value sent by the form:

```
String importador =   httpServletRequest.getParameter("importador");
```

I think setting the name and get thought parameter with httpservletRequest would work, but it didn't.

Anyone knows how I get this value?

**EDIT (SOLVED):**

I solved my problem changing the SelectItem (smartgwt) to ListBox (gwt), because the form is multipart and the servlet can't get its value and the ListBox I got without a problem.

Thnks for the who answered.

Comment: First check the element's name by right click on your page SelectItem element and inspect with Firebug

Comment: It has to have a way through code, because this is not viable

Comment: I set the comboBox's name to importador, and I try to get its value by the httpservlet I it returned null

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get SelectItem selected item's value using combo.getValueAsString() method.
or (String) combo.getValue().

To set SelectItem selectedValue using combo.setValue(string); is this you need?

Comment: No, I need to get the value through the servlet, not just through the combo, because I don't have it there.